# Assigning lambda as default parameter to std::function type

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20, default-arguments

For the following function:

```
template<typename T>
decltype(auto) find_median(
    T begin,
    T end,
    bool sorted = false,
    const std::function<bool()> comparison = [](auto a, auto b)->bool{return a < b;})
{
    assert(begin != nullptr);
    assert(end != nullptr);
    return sorted ? find_median_sorted(begin, end) :
                    find_median_unsorted(begin, end, comparison);
}
```

I cannot call this function without explicitly specifying some `comparison` argument, even though I have a default value set. So I have to call it like the following:

```
find_median(std::addressof(a[0]), std::addressof(a[9]), true, [](){return 1;} );
```

instead of being able to call it as

```
find_median(std::addressof(a[0]), std::addressof(a[9]), true);
```

Why is that?

Comment: `template <typename T, typename F = std::less<void>> decltype(auto) find_median(T, T, bool = false, F comp = {});` seems simpler. (and doesn't have the overhead of `std::function` :) ).

Comment: Avoid `std::function` unless you need to store a general purpose function object in some data structure and call it later.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer here seems to be commented on by @jarod42. The following function signature seems to be the best suited and as he pointed out, does not come with the overhead of std::function
`template <typename T, typename F = std::less<void>> decltype(auto) find_median(T, T, bool = false, F comp = {});`